# Mexican visa requirements for US citizens

Tags: visas, us-citizens, mexico

I'm planning a family trip to Mexico in the summer. I'm a US citizen and so are my two kids. My wife was born in Mexico, but recently became a US citizen as well.

Traveling to Cancun, Mexico our flight will be making a stop in Guadalajara, Mexico  continuing it's way to Cancun on a different plane (flight). We will be in Cancun for nine days.

Should I be aware of something? Mexican visas, or anything else?

Comment: Do mean Mexican *visas* for US citizens? [US State Dept](http://www.travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/mexico.html) says that you can get tourist visas upon arrival. Note: your kids will need passports too.

Comment: That's exactly my concern! since this is my first time traveling to Mexico I didn't know how to come across it. But Yes, that is my question.

Answer (score 4):

US Citizens do not need visas for tourism. They are granted a (usually) 180-day visitor permit upon arrival in Mexico. Just bring your passport.

If the purpose of your trip is business, immigration, etc, then you need to apply for a visa at your local Mexican consulate prior to travel to Mexico.

You can read more [here](http://mexico.usembassy.gov/eng/eacs_sheet.html).

When you arrive in Mexico (in Guadalajara), your wife could, in theory, go through the "Mexican citizens" line for immigration, but instead, I would suggest your family go together through the "Foreigners" line, and explain to the agent that she has dual citizenship.

When re-entering the US, your wife *must* present her US passport, as all US citizens are required to do.

Answer (score -3):

As of March 1, 2010, U.S. citizens and other non-Mexican citizens need passports to enter Mexico. You do not need a passport to enter Mexico if you're a U.S. citizen who is visiting a port town for a day and have come by sea, such as on a cruise.

Comment: Care to rephrase your question?  Just make sure everyone is carrying a passport at all time.  Your situation does not fit that of the passport exception as you're not arriving by sea and have a multi-day trip.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about visas.